# How to define positive integer field that accepts 6 digits only in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to define a database field in `models.py` that accepts only 6 digits in Django.

This is how I define the field in `models.py` but it can accept any positive integer;

```
six_digit_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
```

I am using Django v4.

Comment: You can either use MaxValueValidatior and pass to it max integer which can have 6 digits, or create your own validator to check if value if shorter or equal to 6 digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `validators` for it:

```py
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

six_digit_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(100000), MaxValueValidator(999999)])
```